# Is it possible to use Google IAM users to authenticate users on a backend application? ​

Tags: google-iam

There is an idea to use Google IAM to set up access rights for a backend application.

For example, I have 2 sections in the application: user management and post management.

Is it possible to create roles in Google IAM?

1. user-management with app.users.get rights and app.users.update
2. posts-management with the rights of app.posts.get and app.posts.update

Then I want to add any Google account to Google IAM (using google cloud) and give it the appropriate roles.

Then I want to authorize a Google account in a web application and, using the token and its roles, check access to the section.

Is it possible to do this and how?
I will be glad to any ideas

Comment: No, Google IAM authorizes requests to Google and Google Cloud services. You cannot create custom permissions. Typically that is done using OAuth and custom claims. There are many authorization systems implemented as libraries/frameworks to use. Tip: look into Firebase. They have many features that you will need.